# How best to make a chain method for a hash table in c++?

Tags: c++, hash, hashtable

I am trying to implement a hash table using the chain method and I am faced with a choice. Either it will be a dynamic array of pointers, or an array with a linked list in each cell, as an object of the LinkedList class.

This is how the first method looks conditionally

```
template <typename T, typename V>
class Node {
public:
    T key;
    V value;
    Node* next;
    Node(T key, V value) {
        this->key = key;
        this->value = value;
        this->next = nullptr;
    }
};

template <typename T, typename V>
class HashTable {
private:
    int size;
    int count;
    Node<T, V>** table;
    //...
public: //...
};
```

Should I use it, or create linked lists as objects and add them to the table cells already? How will it be safer for memory?

Comment: The second approach is normal. Not sure what 'safer for memory' means,

Comment: With C++ try to avoid the use of "raw pointers" (and naked new/delete). Instead of `Node<T,V>**` use `std::vector<std::vector<Node<T,V>>`.  Also replace your initialization in the body of your constructor with a [member initializer list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor). This will get rid of all the `this->` code (which is only very rarely needed in template class definitions)

Comment: @PepijnKramer Good advice, in this instance though the vector is very heavy compared to a naked pointer. I.e. decreasing the cache performance by an unnecessarily large factor.

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe It is not my experience that vector has less performance even with the double pointers you end up with scattered memory allocation (one for the table, multiple for all the buckets) so cache coherency should be similar. If performance matters measurements must be made and probably another hash table datastructure selected that is more coherent in memory allocation, and a good hash function for the data must be found (to avoid collisions in the first place). By itself std::vector should not be a perfomance hit over new (with enough initial memory reserved).

Comment: I can't quote a source (so assume it might be wrong). But what I remember from hashing courses is that the last value created is the most likely to be used in the near future. So adding them to the front of a linked list gives you (usually) optimal usage characteristics.

Comment: @MartinYork I have measured a cornucopia of implementations since days of yore. The construction of the table is simplified by just inserting the link/bucket. Avoiding the expensive MOD makes a huge difference, if your data is in L1 (or L2).

Answer (score 2):

> Should I use it, or create linked lists as objects and add them to the table cells already? How will it be safer for memory?

The latter, i.e. you should create a linked list class and have a vector (or your home-grown version thereof) of linked list objects.  The reason is that by creating classes to encapsulate the functionality of linked lists and vectors, you then have clean abstractions that can be tested independently, and your hash table implementation can be at a higher level based on their APIs, rather than being involved with their implementations.

If you ultimate goal is to learn about hash tables, you could start by implementing them using a `std::vector<std::list<std::pair<Key, Value>>>` - get that working first, then - if you have time - replace `std::vector` and `std::list` with your own versions, sticking to the same API.

I'm not sure what you mean by "safer for memory", but clear, structured, more testable code tends to avoid programming errors that corrupt memory or read from unintended places.

By way of contrast, your `Node` class is only a single link ready to be inserted into a linked list, and not the right place to manage overall linked list operations like `push_back` or `push_front`.  Having the hash table have functions like that for the linked list type is mixing responsibilities, which is bad software design.